# File in assistant editor jumping to main editor when breakpoint hit (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, breakpoints

In Xcode, is there a way to prevent my assistant editor's file from hopping back into the main editor whenever a breakpoint there is hit?

I usually have a test in one editor and my source in the other; it's not ideal to have them rearranging like that during debugging.

I've tried all sorts of combinations in Behaviors, but have never quite landed on a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there is! Open up *Preferences…*, click the *Navigation* tab, and select "Uses Focused Editor."

This will leave the breakpointed file in its own editor when the breakpoint is hit, *as long as that editor has focus* (i.e., your cursor is in it). So, not a perfect solution, but still a good one so far.

[image: Xcode preferences pane with Uses Focused Editor selected]